# Drupal - Escape token value

Tags: drupal, escaping, token

I am using this:

`$description = token_replace('[node:field-description]', array('node' => $node));`

in a php code that I have created for a rule. But when a description contains a quote it gives me a PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING. I figure it's because the quote is messing things up.

So my question is how can I escape this token value with php??

Answer (score 0):

try

```
str_replace('"', "", $node);
str_replace("'", "", $node);
```

as far as I rem node is not a string so make sure you use convert value.